# All sites in a site collection automatically redirect output to a default page in site

Tags: form

Steps to replicate the problem:

1. Open a SharePoint (2013) list.
2. Select a list item and click the ellipsis (...) and select either Edit Item or View Item to edit/view details of the list item.
3. Instead of showing the right .aspx page, SharePoint is redirecting output to the default page in the site.
4. This behaviour is seen for every list and every site in the site collection.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Is there a configuration setting for this specific site collection which is causing the problem?

Thank you

Comment: There's no out-of-the-box setting that would do this. It sounds like you have a customization that has run amok. What happens if you type in the url of a valid dispform.aspx page?

Comment: @DerekGusoff When I type the url for a dispform.aspx I am taken to the site's Default.aspx page. To make things worse there is no error message of any kind.

Comment: Was the site collection working properly at some point? And does this happen on all site collections?

Comment: @Erik - I'm not certain whether this site collection has ever worked as expected - I think it hasn't. However other site collections work fine.

Comment: Have you checked to see if someone has modified the master page? If so perhaps try a different OOTB master page and see if the behavior is corrected.

Comment: @Erik - I checked the master  page and there hasn't been any changes.

Comment: It seems the site collection is corrupt. I'll have to create new one.